# MQTT Client only connecting after restarting broker

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I am debugging my python written flask application (using flask_mqtt) I just deployed on a raspberry pi zero wh. On my linux machine (notebook) everything works like a charm, however, on the raspberry pi I discovered that the MQTT client does not acknowledge that it connects to the mosquitto broker although the MQTT log states

```
1589448206: New client connected from ::1 as 15ae66e3-7fc3-4739-a5f5-a0fe16e6ed28 (c1, k5, u'test').
1589448230: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
```

I just discovered that the flask app does acknowledge its connection when I do

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

Does anyone what might cause this?

As I said I use flask_mqtt (https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT) and the follwing callbacks:

```
def subscribe_topics():
for topic in packet_manager.packets.keys():
    mqtt.subscribe(topic)

@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print(" * Connected to MQTT Broker successfully")
    subscribe_topics()
```

and the follwing MQTT settings

```
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = "webserver"
MQTT_BROKER_URL = 'localhost'
MQTT_BROKER_PORT = 1883
MQTT_USERNAME = 'test'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'test'
MQTT_KEEPALIVE = 5
MQTT_TLS_ENABLED = False
```

The print + subscription is only executed after restarting the mosquitto service

EDIT:
I just discovered that mosquitto only sends "CONNACK" after restarting.

I freshly installed **mosquitto version 1.6.8**
The Library I am using only implements MQTTv31 and MQTTv311, is it possible that this is a problem?

Interesting:
When I run the broker on the raspberry pi and connect the MQTT Client on my notebook to the raspberry pi's IP, everything works without restarting mosquitto. Seems like a firewall / loopback problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Please show us your code that produce this behaviour!

Comment: There is something else going on here. Update the question with details of what version of Mosquitto you are running. (It's also worth pointing out that mosquitto doesn't always flush it's log messages in a timely fashion so check the timestamps)

Comment: Also please do not cross post the same question to multiple sites (https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/client-only-connecting-after-restarting-mosquitto) it's usually the same people that will answer and it makes keeping track of updates really hard. The Mods will move a question to the right site if needed.

Comment: thank you @hardillb I won't post the same question on multiple stack sites again, sorry. I edited my post with the installed mosquitto version.